# How to identify if a string has more than one character

Tags: c#

Bear in mind I am new to C#.

I wish to check if a user's input has more than just one character.
Specifically, I wish to ask the user for a Y/N, but if they type "yes" or "no" (or null) to ask them again.

What I have at the moment:

```
char guess;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter");
guess = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

This works well for if the user follows the instructions, but if more than one character is entered, or Enter is pressed, the "Convert.ToChar" fails.

Comment: You can get the length of the input using `string.Length`, but you could instead enforce it by only accepting a single character as Daniel's answer shows.

Comment: You could also try `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault(' '));`

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you do [`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

`.Read` reads the next char off the buffer.

Comment: Maybe he wants them to have to press enter?

Answer (score 1):

I'd still prefer `ReadLine()` over `Read()`, it's more natural for user to press `Enter` after they are done typing. With `Read()` approach you'd have to handle `Backspace` as well, so it gets more complicated. Suggesting something along these lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter");

string input;
while(true)
{
  input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (input.Length == 1) { break; }
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");        
}

char guess = input[0];
```

Notice in the above you can easily add more validation, such as 0-9 not being a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a greater then or less then statement on that.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(input.Length > 1) { Console.WriteLine("Message"); Console.ReadLine(); } // If its bigger then 1 
else { /* if it is one letter do code here */ }
```